# Wrapping open() for unit testing will make gcov not able to open gcda file

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, gcov

I am in the process of implementing using testing for some C program. For this purpose I am using GCC's `-Wl,--wrap=open` in order to mock stdlib's `open()` function and to check that it has been called with the correct options.

When doing so however gcov is having some issues in writing its `.gcda` file. I guess the mock I define is not only used by my tests but also by gcov. Here is a small example of how to reproduce this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int __wrap_open(const char *path, int flags, int mode)
{
    printf("hello from __wrap_open\n");
    return -1;
}


int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

And compile it with `gcc main.c -Wl,--wrap=open -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -lgcov`. In order to keep the example simple I have removed the unit testing part using CMocka in order to show the bug I am encountering.

When running the executable `a.out` I have the following output with GCC and gcov 6.3.0:

```
$ ./a.out
hello from __wrap_open
hello from __wrap_open
profiling:/home/romain/wrap-bug/main.gcda:Cannot open
```

Is there a way to mock the `open()` function for my unit testing purposes *and* to be able to use gcov in order to generate code coverage data? Maybe there is a way to tell gcov to use `__real_open()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to accomplish that would be:

- Check, if the path of the file passed to `open()` is your profiling file
- if yes, pass the call to `__real_open()`

i.e.

```
int __real_open(const char *path, int flags, int mode);

int __wrap_open(const char *path, int flags, int mode)
{
    if (strlen(path) > 5 && !strcmp(path + strlen(path) - 5, ".gcda"))
        return __real_open(path, flags, mode);
    printf("hello from __wrap_open\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Using this way you can of course add more files, which should not be tampered with, easily.

Comment: This works well! I had to add the declaration of `__real_open()` in order to be able to call it. Can you add this in your response and add some spacing around operators so I can mark it as accepted answer?

Comment: @MicroJoe No problem, if you feel better with that ;)

Comment: Also, should I be concerned about close() if I wrap it too? I am actually wrapping both open() and close() but not actually closing anything inside `__wrap_close`. My coverage report works well without calling `__real_close`, I guess the OS will automatically close file descriptor on exit?

Comment: @MicroJoe yes, this is correct. But why do you wrap close at all? And what does the wrapped close do?

Comment: It just checks that close has been correctly called if I simulate an error. Maybe this is overtesting if the OS ensures closing files on exit.

Comment: @MicroJoe well, but you can call __real_close() there, too, with the given filedescriptor handle, this will probably not hurt

Comment: You are right, according to man page close will not complain that much if I try to close a non-existing file descriptor.